# Custom Review prompts for Harman (Adobe) Air apps

Tags: actionscript-3, air, app-store, native

Am i able to use custom preview prompts for an app on Mac App Store. As my understanding, we have to use native API for ratings only on iOS to pass app review. Anyone has experiences on shipping Harman Air apps on Mac App Store can do me a favor. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should Ask your question in https://github.com/Gamua/Adobe-Runtime-Support/discussions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently extended our Application Rater ANE to support macOS which you can use to get the native AppStore review prompts:

https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.ApplicationRater

The update is due out later this month (Feb 2020).